# Riesz representation theorem for the dual of L^\infty and C(X)

Tags: real-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ are real valued nonnegative continuous functions on $\bar\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Moreover, say $\int_\Omega f_n\le 1$ for all n. Then $\{f_n\}$ are bounded in $[L^\infty(\Omega)]^*$ (the dual of $L^\infty(\Omega)$) and $[C(X)]^*$ (the dual of $C(\bar\Omega)$). Right?

If we apply Riesz representation theorem for $[L^\infty(\Omega)]^*$ and Alaoglu theorem, $f_n$ has a subsequence that converges to a bounded finite additive measure $\mu$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. If we apply the representation theorem for $[C(X)]^*$, the subsequence converges to a Randon measure $\nu$. Now, what is the relation of $\mu$ and $\nu$?? Since $\nu$ is countable additive on Borel sets, does that mean $\mu$ is countable additive on Borel sets?

Let's say $\Omega=[0, 1]$ and $f_n$ is affine with $f_n(0)=f_n(\frac{1}{n})=0$ and $f_n(\frac{1}{2n})=2n$ so that $\int_0^1f_n=1$ for each $n$. Question: what is the limit of $f_n$ in  $[C(X)]^*$ and $[L^\infty(\Omega)]^*$?

Comment: You are not applying Alaoglu Theorem correctly. You can  only say there is a **subnet** of $(f_n)$ which conveges in weak* topology.  Subsequence is not guaranteed.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the dual of $L^\infty$ is not sequentially weak-* compact so that I cannot apply the Alaoglu Theorem. But I can still apply Alaoglu Theorem to [C(X)]^*?

Comment: If a nls is separable then the unit ball of the dual is sequentially compact. Not in general. $C(X)$ also need not be separable if $X$ is just compact Hausdorff.  It is separable if $X$ is a compact metric space.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank you so much for your help!!!